# How to use Vector2 {get;set;} for calculating the corners of a square

Tags: c#, xna, get, set

this is my first question and I just started coding in C# some days ago, so please be kind, if I'm doing something stupid. The thing is, I wanna write a small 2D-game in xna and therefore I created a 32x32 px box with texture and that should be the player. I can use the arrow-keys to move the player by writing a class for the player like

```
namespace MyGame
{
    class Player
    {
        public Texture2D Textur;
        public Vector2 Position { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and then using

```
KeyboardState keyboard = Keyboard.GetState();
if (keyboard.IsKeyDown(Keys.Right)) player.Position += new Vector(5,0);
//and so on
```

where 5 is the amount of pixels, the player moves with one keystroke.
What I'm trying is to write something like this

```
class Player
{
    public Texture2D Textur;
    public Vector2 Position { get; set; }
    public Vector2 UpperRightCorner = new Vector2(Position.X + 32, Position.Y);
}
```

But obviously it doesn't work. Even thought I read the documentation on msdn about get; set; I do not really understand, how it works. 
I need the corners, or more precisely the pixel next to the corner, to write a collision method. This method should ask everytime, when I press an arrow-key, what kind of level-block is in front of the player and then adapt the speed resp. set the movement to 0, if there is a solid block (like a wall).

Any idea, how i can write this corner-stuff IN the player class? I can call it in the main class, after instancing the player, but I would prefer to put it into the player class.

Comment: see http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/20703/bounding-box-of-a-rotated-rectangle-2d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're assigning a value to `UpperRightCorner` when it is instantiated. This value will remain unchanged. This could be rewritten with a getter to recalculate `UpperRightCorner` every time it is accessed. Example:

```
public Vector2 UpperRightCorner
{
    get
    {
        return new Vector2(Position.X + 32, Position.Y);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

it won't work as your Position has yet to be created..

In your Player constructor (`public Player()` for example) you must set Position to a `new Vector2` first. For example:

```
public Player()
{
    Position = new Vector2(0,0);
    UpperRightCorner = new Vector2(Position.X + 32, Position.Y);
}
```

Comment: Might want to mention that Mr. Kitopa will also need to update that UpperRightCorner as the player moves as well

Answer (score 1):

Ginosaji's response should give you what you asked for. With a slight modification it can also be made to automatically handle any size texture you choose:

```
public Vector2 UpperRightCorner {
    get {
        return new Vector2(Position.X + Textur.Width, Position.Y);
    }
}
```